# How do I search an Excel column for a value and associate each value with a worksheet that will print to PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to write a code that will scan worksheet values in "N1" and print the data in that row to a PDF using a template found in the workbook, in this case "INS-TDS-7161" and "INS-TDS-7162".

I can get the code to work without the IF THEN statement, but in that case, it will print a PDF for every row regardless of what value is in "N1"

Any suggestions?

```
Sub GenerateDataSheets()
Row = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Cells(Row, 1))
    instrument = Range("N1").Value
    If instrument = "Pressure Gauge" Then
    Sheets("INS-TDS-7161").Range("D2") = Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Cells(Row, 1)
    Sheets("INS-TDS-7161").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Cells(Row, 1)
    Row = Row + 1
    If instrument = "Pressure Transmitter DPT" Then
    Sheets("INS-TDS-7162").Range("D2") = Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Cells(Row, 1)
    Sheets("INS-TDS-7162").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Cells(Row, 1)
    Row = Row + 1
    End If
Loop
Row = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data2").Cells(Row, 1))
    Sheets("Template2").Range("D2") = Worksheets("Data2").Cells(Row, 1)
    Sheets("Template2").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Worksheets("Data2").Cells(Row, 1)
    Row = Row + 1
Loop

MsgBox "DataSheets have been generated.", vbOKOnly, "End"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Seems to me the code is ok but your expected value "Pressure Gauge" is not in cell N1

Answer (score 0):

The code as provided does not compile because it is missing an `End If` statement.  Since it is described as working without the `If` statements, the assumption is that the code you are testing includes this statement.

Once the `End If` statement is added, there are two things that look problematic:

1. Unless one or the other `If` statements are satisfied in the first iteration of the loop, `Row` is never incremented and the the statement
   `Do Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Cells(Row, 1))` will execute using the same value of Row...forever.
2. The statement `instrument = Range("N1").Value` is going to provide `Range("N1")` from the `ActiveSheet`.  Is the `ActiveSheet` intended to be `Worksheets("Pressure Gauge")`?.  The worksheet for `Range("N1")` should be explicitly identified. (e.g., `Worksheets("Pressure Gauge").Range("N1").Value`)

Depending on how many rows of data are involved, it is more efficient to avoid de-referencing the `Worksheets` or `Sheets` collection on every iteration of the loop.  Since the `Worksheet` object remains constant within the loops, declare and set the `Worksheet` variables outside of the loop.

The code below incorporates the above ideas.  Some edits regarding indentation and a helper procedure have been introduced to improve readability and reduce the amount of repeated content.

```
Option Explicit 'Always include the this statement at the top of modules to make the compiler required that all variables are declared

Sub GenerateDataSheets()
    
    Dim pressureGaugeSheet As Worksheet
    Set pressureGaugeSheet = Application.Worksheets("Pressure Gauge")
    
    Dim ins_tds_7161Sheet As Worksheet
    Set ins_tds_7161Sheet = Application.Worksheets("INS-TDS-7161")
    
    Dim ins_tds_7162Sheet As Worksheet
    Set ins_tds_7162Sheet = Application.Worksheets("INS-TDS-7162")

    Dim Row As Long
    Row = 2
    Dim instrument As String
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(pressureGaugeSheet.Cells(Row, 1))
        'Assumes pressureGaugeSheet is the intended worksheet for looking at "N1"
        instrument = pressureGaugeSheet.Range("N1").Value
        
        If instrument = "Pressure Gauge" Then
            ExportPDF pressureGaugeSheet, ins_tds_7161Sheet, Row
        End If ' <-- missing from posted code
        
        If instrument = "Pressure Transmitter DPT" Then
            ExportPDF pressureGaugeSheet, ins_tds_7162Sheet, Row
        End If
        'Move increment of Row outside of `If` statements to ensure it is incremented every iteration
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop
    
    Dim data2Sheet As Worksheet
    Set data2Sheet = Application.Worksheets("Data2")
    
    Dim template2Sheet As Worksheet
    Set template2Sheet = Application.Worksheets("Template2")
    
    Row = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(data2Sheet.Cells(Row, 1))
        ExportPDF data2Sheet, template2Sheet, Row
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "DataSheets have been generated.", vbOKOnly, "End"
End Sub

Private Sub ExportPDF(ByVal sourceSheet As Worksheet, ByVal exportSheet As Worksheet, ByVal Row As Long)
    exportSheet.Range("D2") = sourceSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
    exportSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sourceSheet.Cells(Row, 1)
    
End Sub
```